# XSLT moving items inside other tag at the same level

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this problem for xslt:

This is the input file:

```
  <root>
   <header/>
   <item/>
   … other n-1 <item/>
   <header/>
   <item/>
   … other m-1 <item/>
  </root>
```

so header and item are at the same level (/root).
it must be converted in something like:

```
<root2>
  <header2>
     <item2/>
     …<item2/> // the first n-items up
  </header2>
  <header2>
     <item2/>
     …<item2/> // the last m-items up
  </header2>
</root2>
```

so basically the first n-item must be moved in the first header while the second group of items must be moved in the second header. Any idea how to get this?

Thanks

Randomize

Comment: Good question, +1. A simpler and more efficient solution than the currently accepted one is possible.

Comment: Added also an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: Added an explanation for each of the two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <header/>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <header/>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
</root>
```

XSLT using grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="item" use="count(preceding-sibling::header)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', count(preceding-sibling::header)))]" mode="a"/>
        </root2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="a">
        <header2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k', count(preceding-sibling::header))"/>
        </header2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or simple particular XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root2>
            <header2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item[count(preceding-sibling::header) = 1]"/>
            </header2>
            <header2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item[count(preceding-sibling::header) = 2]"/>
            </header2>
        </root2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both produce the same output:

```
<root2>
  <header2>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
  </header2>
  <header2>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
  </header2>
</root2>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simpler more efficient XSLT 1.0 solution, than counting all preceding siblings**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="item"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::header[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="header"/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header">
  <heather2>
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </heather2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <header/>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <header/>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <heather2>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>3</item>
   </heather2>
   <heather2>
      <item>5</item>
      <item>6</item>
      <item>7</item>
   </heather2>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

A key is defined in such a way that for a `header` any of the immediately-following `item` elements is matched by the `generate-id()` of this `header`.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="item"
        group-adjacent=
         "generate-id(preceding-sibling::header[1])">
     <header2>
      <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
     </header2>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <header2>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>3</item>
   </header2>
   <header2>
      <item>5</item>
      <item>6</item>
      <item>7</item>
   </header2>
</root>
```

**Explanation**: Use of `xsl:for-each-group`, `group-adjacent`, `current-group()`